# Как передать переменную в функцию?

Tags: php

Есть код:

```
$options = array(
   'user'    => 'test',
   'pass'    => '',
   'db'      => 'test'
);
function generate_link($file, $ip,$opts = $options) {
    $phrase = getRandomWord();
    $sql  = "INSERT INTO files SET ip=?s,file=?s,md5=?s";

    $db = new SafeMySQL($opts);
    $db->query($sql,$ip,$file,$phrase);

    return $phrase;
}
```

так вот переменная $options пишет unexpected..Как ее передать туда чтобы все работало?( это нужно для работы с объектом $db и подключения options из внешнего файла.. пробовал по разному и передавать сам объект и  создавать его в другом файле.. не хочет он работать, только если создаю внутри функции работает

Comment: Сразу же написать в `$opts = array(
   'user'    => 'test',
   'pass'    => '',
   'db'      => 'test'
)`, даже если так не будет работать, то в чем проблема запихнуть внутрь функции?

Comment: @Cactus, и для каждой функции где буду использовать эти переменные заного их прописывать?

Comment: Ну этот массив, как я понял, информация для Базы данных. Так вот, вы же функцию один раз пропишите.. и хотите сказать у вас много БД?

Answer (score 1):

Внимание, **правильный** ответ.

Соединение с БД в скрипте всегда должно быть только **одно**, делаться **один** раз, а не при каждом вызове функции заново. Поэтому

```
function generate_link($db, $file, $ip) {
    $phrase = getRandomWord();
    $sql  = "INSERT INTO files SET ip=?s,file=?s,md5=?s";
    $db->query($sql,$ip,$file,$phrase);
    return $phrase;
}
```

а в скрипте пишем так

```
$options = [
   'user'    => 'test',
   'pass'    => '',
   'db'      => 'test'
];
$db = new SafeMySQL($options);
// в идеале все что выше, должно быть в отдельном файле 
// и подключаться через include

$file = 'что-то';
$ip = 'что-то';
echo generate_link($db, $file, $ip);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужен вариант типа "если нет кастомных опций, тогда используем опции по умолчанию", то я бы сделал так:

```
function generate_link($file, $ip,$opts = Null) {

if(empty($opts)) {
  //устанавливаем настройки по умолчанию. Можно взять с какой-то переменной или установить так: 
 $opts = [
   'user'    => 'test',
   'pass'    => '',
   'db'      => 'test'
  ];
}
 // тело функции
}
```

Варианты использования:

```
//с настройками по умолчанию:

   echo generate_link($file, $ip);

// с кастомными настройками:
         $options = [
           'user'    => 'test2',
           'pass'    => '',
           'db'      => 'test'
          ];
    echo generate_link($file, $ip, $options);
```